# Defined type not recognised by pointer initialization

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor, typedef

Trying to define a user-type I stumbled upon an error I don't quite understand: the following code works fine

```
const int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

typedef const int costant;

costant b = 5;
costant *c = a;

void func( const int item )
{
    printf("Item: %i\n", item );
}

int main( void )
{
    func( a[0] );
    func( b );
    func( *c );
}
```

Nonethe less, initializing the pointer

```
costant *c = a[0];
```

fails stating that `Initializer element is not costant`. Trying to access the location `a[0]` to alter its content is refused with error `assignment of read-only location`.

Why is considered the array address `a` as const but not its element `a[0]`, even though it is "read-only"?

Replacing the `typedef` with a `#define costant const int` doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: The typedef line doesn't compile. Please do not present uncompilable code.

Comment: `costant * c = &a[0];` would work (assuming a fixed typedef) -- because a[0] is a `const int` but `c` is a `pointer to a const int`

Comment: This code **does not** work fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I corrected the typedef line. It does compile now

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `#define`, which has the syntax `#define NEW_SYMBOL [old_symbol]`, the syntax of `typedef` is:

```
typedef existing_type new_type;
```

So:

```
typedef const int constant;
```

Is valid C, whereas

```
typedef constant const int;
```

Is not.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the mistake (I just copied wrongly from my editor in another pc)